# POS tagger for Latin Python

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech, latin

Any idea if there are any more POS taggers for Latin apart from CLTK available for Python or any other language? I have tried the CLTK POS taggers but they are not giving me very accurate results for my corpus

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with this and check: https://pypi.org/project/polyglot/

Comment: does not support Latin for POS tagging

Comment: I saw Latin under languages they support https://pypi.org/search/?c=Natural+Language+%3A%3A+Latin

Comment: But not for all NLP. Latin can be used for detecting the language